# e.stopPropagation() and jQuery.hover()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to have both of these work together or do I have to try using the mouseenter and mouseleave instead?

Comment: I’m not aware that there is a hover event at all (well, it’s not even in listed in DOM 3 Events). all I know is the CSS pseudo-class.

Answer (score 22):

You can use [`event.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) with [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/), but you're *actually* using [`mouseenter`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and [`mouseleave`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) with [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) anyway.  If you provide 1 function to `.hover()`, it runs on both events, if you provide 2 functions, the first is the `mouseenter` handler, the second is the `mouseleave` handler.

However, this may not be what you're after...since `mouseenter` doesn't fire **when entering a child**, that's actually specifically why it exists, [`mouseout`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/) *will* fire when entering a child.  [You can see that's there's no difference in a demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/D7jwq/), hover from top to bottom, comment and uncomment out the `.stopPropagation()`, it makes no difference...because the event doesn't bubble to the parent.

However if you are using [`mouseover`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/) and [`mouseout`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/), *then* it would matter, like this:

```
$("li").mouseover(function(e) {
    $(this).addClass("red").parents().removeClass("red");
}).mouseout(function(e) {
    $(this).removeClass("red");
});​
```

*Now* we have a bubbling problem, because the event bubbles right up, adding the class to the parent we just removed it from, [see a demo of the problem here](http://jsfiddle.net/D7jwq/1/).  However if we *stop* that bubble, with the [`.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/), we get the desired effect, like this:

```
$("li").mouseover(function(e) {
    $(this).addClass("red").parents().removeClass("red");
    e.stopPropagation();
}).mouseout(function(e) {
    $(this).removeClass("red");
});​
```

[You can see in this demo how this works differently](http://jsfiddle.net/D7jwq/2/).

In short: **yes** [`event.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) works with [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/), but most likely, it's not *exactly* what you're after.