# In jquery, how do I highlight only the div under the cursor using the hover function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I just want to `border` only the 'div' under the blue point by using `.hover()` function in the image below.  But as you can see, there are red borders around many of the `div` elements.

[image: a busy cat]

My code is:

```
$(function(){
$("div").hover(function(e){
    $(e.currentTarget).css({"border": "solid red 2px"})
}, function(e){
    $(e.currentTarget).css({"border": "none"})
})
})
```

But the result is unexpected, as indicated above.  **How do I highlight only the div under the cursor?**

**THANKS kdbanman - ANSWER is below**

I edit this question because the answer of **kdbanman** is solve my problem but a little more code should be add. This is the full code.

```
$(function(){
    $("div").mouseover(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        if (e.redBorderDrawn) return;
        $(this).css({"border": "solid red 2px"});
        e.redBorderDrawn = true;
    }).mouseout(function(e) {
        $(this).css({"border": "none"})
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your hover event is [bubbling up your entire tree of `div` elements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2949018/3367144), so use `stopPropagation()` to prevent the event from bubbling up the tree.

```
$(function(){
    $("div").hover(function(e){
        $(e.currentTarget).css({"border": "solid red 2px"})
        e.stopPropagation();
    }, function(e){
        $(e.currentTarget).css({"border": "none"})
    })
})
```

**HOWEVER, using `.stopPropagation()` on `hover` and `mouseout` for all `div` elements might kill other mouse hover behavior/effects for them.  The above code is just to demonstrate the event bubbling problem.**  It's much safer to set a custom flag on the event and allow it to propagate:

```
$(function(){
    $("div").hover(function(e){
        if (e.redBorderDrawn) return;

        $(e.currentTarget).css({"border": "solid red 2px"});
        e.redBorderDrawn = true;
    }, function(e){
        $(e.currentTarget).css({"border": "none"})
    })
});
```

Also, the second callback to `hover` (the one for `mouseleave`) is not called when a child element is entered.  Add the same border removal callback to the `mouseout` event to handle that case:

```
$(function(){
    $("div").mouseout(function(e){
         $(e.currentTarget).css({"border": "none"})
    })
})
```

Now the hover behavior looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Give it an ID and change your code to

```
$("#YOUR_ELEMENT_ID").hover(function(e)
{
    $(this).css({"border": "solid red 2px"})
}, function(e)
{
    $(this).css({"border": "none"})
});
```

Comment: i can't write the `.hover()` function for each id. @@. I just want to action in `div`.

Comment: Then use a `class` to target the elements

Comment: change id to class as @Rafa said

Comment: Even using a class won't necessarily solve OP's problems - what if elements of said class are nested?  The event will still bubble up the tree and put the border on everything.

Comment: Moreover, OP specifically asks for the `div` under the mouse, not one of a specific ID or class.

Comment: No, i think `div`, `class` or `id` is the same in this situation. :( **kdbanman** solve my problem. We should learn it. But don't vote down this answer, i don't know so i ask, **Diptox** think he know so he answer. He can not comment because he have a code block. We should understand, everyone need help.